# How to launch Mail app and attach image from applicationStorageDirectory in iPhone using Adobe Air

Tags: iphone, image, email, air, adobe

I've tried:

```
var fn:String = "image.png";
var f:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath(fn);
var subject:String = "My encrypted Image";
var body:String = "<html><head><body><img src=\""+f.url+"\"></body></head></html>";
var url:String = "mailto:?subject="+subject+"&body=" + body;
navigateToURL( new URLRequest( url ), '_self' );
```

This does launch the Mail app but it displays a "?" icon, which means it can't find my full app-storage path.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

instead of putting the file path, put a Base64 encoded string of the image, for example:

```
<img src=\"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==\" alt=\"Red dot\" />
```

More info:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

To convert from ByteArray to Base64:
http://www.lorenzgames.com/blog/convert-an-image-to-base64-string-and-vice-versa

Answer (score 0):

You might also try the GoViral ane from MilkMan Games.

```
  http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/goviral-ane-ios.html
```

Search that page for showEmailComposerWithBitmap()